# How to upsert multiple rows in key-value table in sqlite?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I wrote a function in my app to upsert multiple rows in sqlite in a  table.

The table is created as:

```
CREATE TABLE KeyValueTable ( ObjectName TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, ObjectValue BLOB)
```

The function is:

```
private bool Set(IEnumerable<(string key, object value, Type type)> collection)
{
    try
    {
        using (var connection = CreateConnection())
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
            {
                foreach (var item in collection)
                {
                    var serialized = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item.value, item.type, null);
                    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        command.CommandText = @"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO KeyValueTable VALUES (@ObjectName, @ObjectValue)";
                        command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@ObjectName", item.key));
                        command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@ObjectValue", serialized));

                        try
                        {
                            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        catch (InvalidOperationException)
                        {
                            transaction.Rollback();
                            return false;
                        }

                    } // using
                } // foreach

                transaction.Commit();
                return true;
            } // using
        }
    }
    catch (SQLiteException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Not sure if this is the best way as I am creating command per item in the collection.

Is there a better more efficient method to do this ?

Comment: Create the command outside the loop, add the params using the overload that just wants the type then inside the loop simply update the values with `command.Parameters[0].Value = item.key;` & execute.

Comment: @AlexK. What would that type be for the ObjectValue(Blob)?

Comment: DbType.Binary for a blob

Comment: I did change that and I am getting this error `Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'.'`

Comment: Converting to byte[] by using `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serialized)` worked but not sure if this is correct encoding to use for serialized objects.